# MySQL GROUP BY on a float field

Tags: mysql, group-by, floating-accuracy

I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
ID int, DISTANCE float, EVENT Varchar
```

What i would like to acheive is to select all the data, but to group by the event and distance fields (i.e. to remove duplicate events at the same distance).

The issue I can see is that the `Distance` column is a float, and as such the `GROUP BY` may not behave expectantly. Most (i say most) of the data is stored to 3 decimal places, and this is the criteria I would like to group on.

Example Data:

ID,Distance,Event

```
1, 0.001, A
2, 0.002, A
3, 0.002, A
4, 0.002, B
5, 0.003, C
6, 0.0035,C
```

So the result would look like:

```
1, 0.001, A
2, 0.002, A
4, 0.002, B
5, 0.003, C
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CAST()` to convert the decimal to string and only use the first 5 characters of the converted string (`"x.xxx"`), which you can then group on with `GROUP BY`:

Ex:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    CAST(Distance AS CHAR(5)) AS DistanceGroup,
    Event
FROM 
    yourtbl
GROUP BY
    DistanceGroup,
    Event
```

**EDIT**: You can also use `TRUNCATE()` on the `Distance` field which may actually be better in terms of performance:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TRUNCATE(Distance, 3) AS DistanceGroup,
    Event
FROM 
    yourtbl
GROUP BY
    DistanceGroup,
    Event
```

Additional info on [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [TRUNCATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate)

Answer (score 2):

Change float to decimal. See [Problems with Floating-Point Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)

Comment: I know this would be the ideal solution, but no I cant do this. There must be a way to GROUP BY Distance to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Why cannot you do it? Just alter Distance column to decimal(18,5) or so

Comment: There are numerous database out of my control. I will look into it. In the meantime, hopefully someone out there has another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `FLOAT` type. Use `DECIMAL` instead. Float converts decimal numbers to binary which results in rounding (loss of precision). Decimal stores the numbers as decimals - no conversion.

If you are not allowed to update the table definition, than in the query, cast the float column to DECIMAL.